# Is there an Option in Eclipse to switch how selected lines are displayed?

Tags: eclipse, editor, line, selection

Is there some way to configure the Eclipse Editor
to show only the actual content of
selected lines
rather than the entire editor width?

For example, 2 Screenshots:
_1) this Text in Notepad++
_2) this Text in Eclipse

[image: Notepad++ Selection]

[image: Eclipse Selection]

Comment: Put the cursor in the Console view and press Ctrl+A.  Eclipse will highlight the actual characters.

Comment: That wasn't the question. Eclipse marks the width of the Editor rather than the width of the content. Take another look at the Screenshots. I've amended the Text to make that clearer.